# Why i2c_device_id is defined separately and not part of i2c_client

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Why do we have a separate structure called `i2c_device_id` when we had `i2c_client` already?

The following is the definition of `i2c_device_id` :

```
struct i2c_device_id {
    char name[I2C_NAME_SIZE];
    kernel_ulong_t driver_data; /* Data private to the driver */
};
```

We already have `char name[I2C_NAME_SIZE];` in `i2c_client`. We could also have stored `driver_data` inside `i2c_client`. Why was there a need to define a separate structure called as `i2c_device_id`. I feel redundant. Can someone please help me what I am missing out as I believe I do.

**EDIT**

It seems like its moreover related to the history. Please correct me if I am wrong.
`i2c_device_id` is there from a long time. Then came `of_device_id` and `acpi_device_id`. Using either of them should be enough, however, they are not mututally exclusive and can be mixed. This is the reason if a device tree is being used and the driver also has `i2c_device_id` table defined, the probe also receives `i2c_device_id` of the matching device. I tried this on a sensor to validate.

However, to me they should be mutually exclusive. The `platform_match` looks like this : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/platform.c#L965

So if a device tree based match succeeded (OF), then as per definition, it returns from there, without proceeding for `i2c_device_id` table match. Hence, the driver probe should receive NULL for `i2c_device_id`. But this is not the case. Can someone please help to find why I am still getting `i2c_device_id` in the driver probe, when the device tree match (OF) is happening.

Comment: Some PCI and USB media devices have onboard I2C adapters and I2C client chips. And their device drivers make use of common sub-drivers for the I2C client chips. For example, consider the callers of `dvb_module_probe()` which requests a module and creates an I2C client device with a specified name that is matched against the I2C client driver's module device table. Since these are plug-and-play devices (not part of the base system), there is no device-tree or ACPI information for the devices.

Comment: There is a new callback, called `->probe_new()` in I2C framework, it's exactly tells you that *i2c_device_id* is a legacy stuff, however, as @IanAbbott mentioned, there are cases when you might have need a match against the legacy ID (though ideally it should be done via newest **swnode** framework or alike).